# Canvas, changing movement of animated objects

Tags: canvas, move, shapes, radius

So I have 2 objects moving right now, circles and squares.  Both of them function fine, except for the movement of the square.  It has a very small radius which it rotates around, while the circle has a larger one.

I'm not sure exactly what code to manipulate to change the squares because all my tinkering does nothing.

Here is my set up for movement for both of them.  I've been trying to mirror them to no avail.

```
function setupCircles() {
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var randomX = Math.round(-200 + Math.random() * 700);
    var randomY = Math.round(-200 + Math.random() * 700);
    var speed = .2 + Math.random() * 3;
    var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;
    var radius = 5 + Math.random() * 100;

    var circle = new Circle(radius, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
    circles.push(circle);
}
drawAndUpdate();
}
setupCircles();

function setupSquares() {
for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    var randomX = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var randomY = Math.round(-100 + Math.random() * 700);
    var speed = .2 + Math.random() * 3;
    var size = 5 + Math.random() * 100;
    var radius = 2 + Math.random() * 100;

    var square = new Square(radius, speed, size, randomX, randomY);
    squares.push(square);
}
drawAndUpdate();
}
 setupSquares();
```

Also for reference, here's the object itself

```
  function Circle(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
  this.radius = radius;
  this.speed = speed;
  this.width = width;
  this.xPos = xPos;
  this.yPos = yPos;
  this.opacity = .1 + Math.random() * .5;

  this.counter = 0;

  var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

  if (signHelper == 1) {
    this.sign = -1;
  } else {
    this.sign = 1;
  }
  }

 function Square(radius, speed, width, xPos, yPos) {
 this.speed = speed;
 this.width = width;
 this.xPos = xPos;
 this.yPos = yPos;
 this.opacity = .1 + Math.random() * .5;

this.counter = 0;

var signHelper = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

if (signHelper == 1) {
    this.sign = -1;
} else {
    this.sign = 1;
}
}
```

Comment: can u make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstration this behaviour?

Comment: Here it is 
https://jsfiddle.net/z8L6fsn2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you're missing *this.radius in your square's update, without it your squares are moving around such a tiny circle that the movement isn't perceptible, that line of code should be:

```
mainContext.fillRect(this.xPos + Math.cos(this.counter / 100) *this.radius, this.yPos + Math.sin(this.counter / 100)*this.radius, 50, 50);
```

here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z8L6fsn2/1/

Comment: Ahh, overlooked that when transferring it to the square, thank you!